# Jest run async function ONCE before all tests

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to use jest for my server unit testing (instead of mocha+chai).
Is there a way I can run async function before all tests start (init purposes) only once and not for every test file? And also if there's a way of running something after all tests are done?

Answer (score 82):

This feature was added in [Jest's 22 version](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#globalsetup-string), with `globalSetup` and `globalTeardown` configurations.
Look at [this](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3832) for examples.

<sub>package.json (or in [jest.config.js](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration))</sub>

```json
{
  ...
  "jest": {
    "globalSetup": "./scripts/jestGlobalSetup.js"
  }
}
```

<sub>/scripts/jestGlobalSetup.js</sub>

```js
module.exports = async () => {
  console.log('\nhello, this is just before tests start running');
};
```

OR

```js
export default async () => {
  console.log('\nhello, this is just before tests start running');
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot do anything Jest related in that file (except accessing the options), like setting up global mocks, because the global `jest` object is not available and you cannot import it outside of a test file.

Answer (score 21):

Jest provides [`beforeAll`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/api.html#beforeallfn-timeout) and [`afterAll`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/api.html#afterallfn-timeout). As with [`test`/`it`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/api.html#testname-fn-timeout) it will wait for a promise to resolve, if the function returns a promise.

```
beforeAll(() => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // Asynchronous task
    // ...
    resolve();
  });
});
```

It also supports callback style, if you have some existing test code that uses callbacks, although it's recommended to use promises.

```
beforeAll(done => {
  // Asynchronous task
  // ...
  done();
});
```

Comment: [Jest `beforeAll`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/api.html#beforeallfn-timeout) sounds great, especially re: Promises "If the function returns a promise or is a generator, Jest waits for that promise to resolve before running tests." Does Jasmine have the equivalent? It looks like Jasmine does *not* support Promises, but [*does* support a `done` callback approach?](https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) I'm specifically using Protractor, but the `done` callback doesn't work for me [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34892316/1175496),

Comment: where can I find the docs that state it can use `done()` in `beforeAll`? I can only find it waits for [promise](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#beforeallfn-timeout)

Comment: Good answer, but not satisfying the requested "only once and not for every test file".

Comment: This answer is wrong, this happens one time per test file

Comment: There is no need to return a promise, you can use async/await `beforeAll(async () => {})`

Answer (score 9):

jest provides options for both global setup and teardown in new versions. You can create files for both setup and teardown exporting an async function and provide that path in jest configurarion like this.

```
"globalSetup": "setup-file-path",
"globalTeardown": "tear-down-file-path"
```

You can read about it further [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#globalsetup-string)

Comment: Downvoted due to not including a link to a source reference.

Answer (score 5):

If you execute jest tests with npm you can run any node command or any executable before executing other command

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node setup.js && jest"
  }
```

so now you can run this with command

```
$ npm t
```

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for Jest solution. Like Mocha allows you to put BeforeAll at a global scope I was hoping Jest has something similar.

Comment: While this solution is ok, this wont run in `--watch` mode. Is there any Jest solution?

Comment: this answer is out of date

Answer (score 1):

It's become very easy when you use **beforeAll** function **outside the describe block** and then assign async keyword to it.

Note: I am using jest @**27.4.3** version here

> code sample

```
import { getValuesFromAWSSecretManager } from '../../src/libs/secret_manager';
import quickbooksConfigFrom from '../../src/config/quickbooks';

const quickbooksConfig = quickbooksConfigFrom;

// calling the async beforeALL function to get values from AWS Secret Manager
beforeAll(async () => {
  const secretData = await getValuesFromAWSSecretManager();
  quickbooksConfig.clientId = secretData.QUICKBOOKS_CLIENT_ID;
  quickbooksConfig.clientSecret = secretData.QUICKBOOKS_CLIENT_SECRET;
});

describe('Quickbooks config file should be defined', () => {
  test('Quickbooks File should be exist', () => {
    expect(quickbooksConfig).toBeDefined();
  });

  test('Quickbooks File should be exist and having values', () => {
    expect(quickbooksConfig).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

hope it helps and solves your doubts,

and you might need to do it in each file to apply.

you can check jest beforeAll documentation [from here](https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown#one-time-setup)