# Jest-js Pupetter await puppeteer launch newPage returns undefined

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer

I want to run a test using puppetter, I setup the test using puppetter `beforeAll` and use `done` parameter to finish the setup

```
beforeAll(async (done) => {  
  try{
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      slowMo: 20,
      args: [`--window-size=${width},${height}`]
    })
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setViewport({ width, height })
    done()
  } catch (e){
    fail("SETUP FAILED:\n"+e)
  }
}
```

and the `test`, the test will run after `beforeAll` is `done` right?

```
test('Test Invalid Username Password', async () => {
    try {
      await page.goto(APP_URL)
      await page.click('[data-testid="form-username"]')
      await page.keyboard.type(username)
      //omitted
    } catch (e) {
      fail('AN EXCEPTION IS THROWED\n'+e)
    }
  }, 200000);
```

I got error `Cannot read property 'goto' of undefined"`

why does it sometimes return `undefined` and sometimes not? 
I suppose this is because of the chromium isn't yet ready? but I already write `await`, isn't that enough?

what else to check before the chromium is ready to be used? not undefined?

**UPDATE**

the error when it is undefined

```
Test Invalid Username Password

    Failed: "AN EXCEPTION IS THROWED
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'goto' of undefined"

      51 |       expect(errorMessage).toEqual(loginExpectedResult.TEST_INVALID_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD)
      52 |     } catch (e) {
    > 53 |       fail('AN EXCEPTION IS THROWED\n'+e)
         |       ^
      54 |     }
      55 |   }, 200000);
      56 |

      at Env.fail (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:656:39)
      at Object.fail (test/logintest/login.test.js:53:7)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:65:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:303:22)
      at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:117:21)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (test/logintest/login.test.js:17:103)
      at _next (test/logintest/login.test.js:19:194)
      at test/logintest/login.test.js:19:364
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/logintest/login.test.js:19:97)
```

the `fail()` is come from jasmine perhaps? I found it using VSCode autocomplete. I thought it was from Jest. can't it be used?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `fail("SETUP FAILED:\n"+e)` call to `console.log("SETUP FAILED:\n"+e)` and let us know what it logs.

I had the same problem as I started reproducing your issue because I forgot a `require('puppeteer')` command for example...

Some more considerations:

- you don't need a `done()` call, the `beforeAll` function is async and you await every single Puppeteer call so... the function terminates by itself without the need for a `done()` call. Remove it even from the passed params
- you call `fail` but where is it defined?
- remove the big `try/catch` around everything, the test fails automatically with useful insights in case of error, an additional surrounding `try/catch` doesn't bring you any advantages and make your tests more verbose

Let me know if it's helpful

**UPDATE**

In the comments another question about it is

> oh and where can I find the docs that beforeAll waits for async function to be finished?

Well, I start from the beginning:

The 'beforeAll' function is just a regular JS function

```
beforeAll(() => {  
  // do your sync stuff
}
```

so if you're making some async stuff inside it

```
beforeAll(() => {  
  setTimeout(() => {
    // ...
  }, 1000);
}
```

it can't know that it should wait for something, that's why you can leverage the `done` function

```
beforeAll((done) => {  
  setTimeout(() => {
    done();
  }, 1000);
}
```

so Jest doesn't considera it "done" until you manually call the `done` function itself.
The same values for a promise

```
beforeAll((done) => {  
  yourFunctionThatReturnsAPromise(() => {
    done();
  });
}
```

or some promise concatenation

```
beforeAll((done) => {  
  yourFunctionThatReturnsAPromise(() => {
    return anotherPromise();
  }).then(() => {
    return anotherPromise();
  }).then(() => {
    done();
  });
}
```

and we can shorten it more

```
beforeAll((done) => {  
  yourFunctionThatReturnsAPromise(() => anotherPromise())
    .then(() => anotherPromise())
    .then(() => done());
}
```

**Async/Await**
`async/await` is been added to better manage the promise chains, let's see how we can transform the latter function

```
beforeAll(async (done) => {  
  await yourFunctionThatReturnsAPromise())
  await anotherPromise();
  done();
}
```

- we `await` every promise
- we add `async` to the function passed to `beforeAll`

Doing so every promise is automatically waited and we tell JS that our function is asynchronous and it automatically waits for the promises completion before considering our function completed. And since it waits automatically... we can now remove the `done` use

```
beforeAll(() => {  
  await yourFunctionThatReturnsAPromise())
  await anotherPromise();
}
```

Now we can apply that to your script: remember that almost every Puppeteer's function returns a promise so we could write a setup function like so

```
beforeAll((done) => {  
  puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    slowMo: 20,
    args: [`--window-size=${width},${height}`]
  }).then(browser => {
    return browser.newPage();
  }).then(page => {
    return page.setViewport({ width, height });
  }).then(() => {
    done();
  })
}
```

and transform it to the original one

```
beforeAll(async (done) => {  
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    slowMo: 20,
    args: [`--window-size=${width},${height}`]
  })
  page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.setViewport({ width, height })
  done()
}
```

but since it's an async function and you `await` all the Puppeteer's calls you can now remove the `done` function

```
beforeAll(async () => {  
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    slowMo: 20,
    args: [`--window-size=${width},${height}`]
  })
  page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.setViewport({ width, height })
}
```

because an `async` function is automatically awaited, it doesn't end without waiting for the promises (the ones you `await` obviously) to be resolved.

Comment: I already updated the question, oh and where can I find the docs that `beforeAll` waits for async function to be finished? I can only find using [promise](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#beforeallfn-timeout) and using [done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315679/jest-run-async-function-once-before-all-tests). I just started using jest 

Comment: and I use the try catch because apparently if I didn't sometimes it jumps to `afterAll` returns the error there. the previous exception isn't printed. so I don't have a clue what's going on

Comment: is it because my memory is almost full? I struggle just to open the chromium because my memory usage is more than 92%.
I tried stopping docker service that eats most of my memory, and it worked. but I don't know

Comment: I've updated my answer with a detailed explanation about async/await. Note that it isn't related to Jest itself but to how the `async/await` API work. Anyway, I hope it helps you. Let me know if it's enough clear and in case accepts the answer 

Comment: Thanks for the `async/await` explanation! I still get the error sometimes, is it possible that my memory is too occupied? and sometimes above error, sometimes I got error `Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed. This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with --detectOpenHandles to troubleshoot this issue.`

Comment: I tried with parameter `--detectOpenHandles` and it didn't tell me anything

Comment: That's unrelated to this question, raise another question for that with a complete how-to-reproduce description so the info will be useful to other users too 