# How should I get API token before executing Unit Test cases?

Tags: javascript, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

Within my unit test cases, I'm trying to do unit tests against some data in the API therefore an API token is required. I'm hoping to find a way to call token API and store it in Redux before firing any API.

I'm aware of `setup.js` in Jest, tried calling my API there and store in Redux didn't work well. I don't think the `setup.js` waited the method to finish completely before starting the unit test.

```
// Within the Setup.js, I was calling method directly
const getAPItoken = async() => {
     await getToken();
}
getAPItoken();
```

Currently I'm getting the API token in 1 of the Unit Test files. Upon the method completion, rest of the Unit Tests will run fine since they are getting the API token from Redux.

**Sample of what I'm doing now**

```
describe('Get API token', () => {
  test('it should return true after getting token', async () => {

    // Within the method itself, it actually store the token to redux upon receiving from API, also it will return TRUE upon success
    const retrievedToken = await getToken();

    expect(retrievedToken).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Could you give a [mre] to illustrate what specifically you tried and what _"didn't work well"_ means?

Comment: Im looking for [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315679/jest-run-async-function-once-before-all-tests).. call one method before running the test, but I want to apply to all files instead just 1 test file

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`globalSetup`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#globalsetup-string). It accepts an async function that is triggered once before all test suites.

So you can optain the API key and set it on node `global` object so you can access if from anywhere.

```js
// setup.js
module.exports = async () => {
  global.__API_KEY__ = 'yoru API key';
};
```

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
    globalSetup: './setup.js',
};
```

Comment: Hi @Ivan, im not looking to get API key. Im trying to get API token (JWT Token)

Comment: How are you getting the token? It's some kind of API call right? Are you passing cookies? Can you post the token call code?

Comment: Hi Ivan, my goal is just to get an authentication token from the server before running any test cases. So in my mind, Im trying to get the token from `setup.js` and store it in redux. While running all the test cases, I'll call the APIs with token from Redux.

Apparently this doesn't work well.. i realized redux get reset everytime after executing one test file.